# How to flatMap a function on GroupedDataSet in Apache Flink

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-flink

I want to apply a function via `flatMap` to each group produced by `DataSet.groupBy`. Trying to call `flatMap` I get the compiler error:

```
error: value flatMap is not a member of org.apache.flink.api.scala.GroupedDataSet
```

My code:

```
var mapped = env.fromCollection(Array[(Int, Int)]())
var groups = mapped.groupBy("myGroupField")
groups.flatMap( myFunction: (Int, Array[Int]) => Array[(Int, Array[(Int, Int)])] )  // error: GroupedDataSet has no member flatMap
```

Indeed, in the documentation of [flink-scala 0.9-SNAPSHOT](http://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.flink.api.scala.GroupedDataSet) no `map` or similar is listed. Is there a similar method to work with? How to achieve the desired distributed mapping over each group individually on a node?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `reduceGroup(GroupReduceFunction f)` to process all elements a group. A `GroupReduceFunction` gives you an `Iterable` over all elements of a group and an `Collector` to emit an arbitrary number of elements.

Flink's `groupBy()` function does not group multiple elements into a single element, i.e., it does not convert a group of `(Int, Int)` elements (that all share the same `_1` tuple field) into one `(Int, Array[Int])`. Instead, a `DataSet[(Int, Int)]` is logically grouped such that all elements that have the same key can be processed together. When you apply a `GroupReduceFunction` on a `GroupedDataSet`, the function will be called once for each group. In each call all elements of a group are handed together to the function. The function can then process all elements of the group and also convert a group of `(Int, Int)` elements into a single `(Int, Array[Int])` element.

Comment: Isn't this same as `GroupCombineFunction`?